# In this example why do I need CRTP?

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp

See **Object counter** example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern#Object_counter): Why it just does not inherit from non-template `class counter`. Why counter should be template?

```
template <typename T>
struct counter
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specializations will give you different `counter`s for different types.
Note that those counters are static data members, thus shared among all instances of the given specialization.

Comment: aaaahh, those counters are static, right? stupid question :D

Comment: @Narek Each question seems stupid once answered. ;-)

Comment: @skypjack _"Each question seems stupid once answered"_ Well, there is blatant stupid stuff sometimes, and you should seriously prefix your answer with a disclaimer to get on a _forehead protection_ before reading further. The OP will tend to heavily injury themselves banging their head against a wall or just the desktop in front.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Hope you are not over-excited about this question, dear blatant ;)

Comment: @skypjack I'm not even sure, if the OP might sue you for such injuries in the U.S., because you forgot to give the warning. They have a weird legislative system. ;-)

Comment: Popcorn and beer sounds good. It's almost 8PM in Italy. What about a good movie to watch meanwhile? :-D

Comment: @skypjack _"What about a good movie to watch meanwhile?"_ _Big Bang Theory_ is running sideways on the big plasma TV :-D ...

Comment: You win. That's all. We are to be banned from SO, but it was worth it. ;-)

Comment: Of course it was worth the fun. I think  that @Narek will get over my downvote, and you will enjoy my upvote. I'm pretty sure none of us will get banned about this funny Q&A pair.

Comment: We still can do something to get banned. Seams we make here a FB. LinkedIn has become FB now it is time of Stackoverflow. GitHub is the next :D